# Handling column responses in Zapier, where one column is blank

Tags: json, webhooks, zapier, formatter

In Zapier, I'm getting this response from an API.

[Zapier GUI response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sywPS.png)

In JSON it looks like this:

```
                        {   "ColumnName": "Column Name",
                            "ColumnValue": "Test Name"
                        },
                        { "ColumnName": "Date Reported to the Above", "ColumnValue": "" },
                        { "ColumnName": "Time Reported to the Above", "ColumnValue": "" },
                        {
                            "ColumnName": "Date Logged",
                            "ColumnValue": "2020-05-25"
                        },
                        { "ColumnName": "Time Concern Logged", "ColumnValue": "" },
```

This is a perfect response, and i would be able to work with this response fine, but unfortunately Zapier is splitting each column into a string for future steps, so the response doesn't remain in-tact.

This is resulting in some strange behaviour, because when I split the strings, it's completely skipping the blanks, resulting in a mismatched number of Column Name and Column Value entries, meaning I can't re-build the object in future steps, as I will get 22 Column Names and I'm left with only 17 Column Values, where all of the blanks are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved this.

Zapier's trying to be helpful by giving us the response like this:

```
{{88974381__Result__Customfields[]ColumnName}}
```

However you can actually get rid of the ColumnName and use the whole object. Lovely.

```
{{88974381__Result__Customfields}}
```

One thing to note, is that it still doesn't give me the nice object that once was, but at least it gives me a string which I can apply some regex to. This definitely seems like a bug, because it's unfortunate that Zapier takes away a format that was already there, and makes you re-build it from a string

...Unless I'm missing something.

This was a bit painful